# google map getting refreshed in Satellite View while drawing polyline and setting marker

Tags: android, google-maps

I have to draw polyline for live tracking of vehicles, everything is working fine in the `normal mode` of the map.
But when I am switching from `normal to satellite mode`, map getting refreshed every time when drawing the `polyline`, in result screen is `fluctuating`.

The screenshot is as below at the time of refreshing map:
[image]

Comment: post your code...maybe you are calling the map type every time...

Comment: yeah.. you are right it was there in thread call thanks buddy. Now it's working fine